# pH Sensor with current loop

Tags: converter, ph

I have a ph sensor(S272CD) that give the output from -2000mV to +2000mV. I need to interface it into a current loop converter(XTR117). The current loop ic will accept only 0 to 5v. How can i connect this sensor to the current loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is level-translator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy3pFZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>